# How do I get gettext and poedit to work with WAMP?

Tags: php, windows-7, wamp, gettext

I am trying to get gettext and poedit to work on windows. Here is my test code:

```
<?php
require_once("localization.php");
echo _("Hello World!");
?>`
```

and

```
<?php
$locale = "de_DE";
if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
textdomain("messages");
?>
```

I am using this tutorial: [link](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/). I have the gettext extension enabled via WAMP. 
Unfortunately when I navigate to the page, it shows "Hello World!" instead of the expected "Hallo Walt!"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Setting `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');` does not work either =(

Comment: Here is a copy of the .mo http://pastie.org/4801074

Comment: I tried it on my ubuntu server as well... no luck. For what it's worth; I don't think I need to use a localization as I am doing 1:1 translations of a fictitious language.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu I had to `sudo apt-get install gettext` and then `sudo locale-gen de_DE` to get this to work. I still haven't found a fix for windows =(